# Trouble accessing passed locals in Rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's the relevant area from my parent view:

```
<h1>New Bet</h1>

<%= form_for :bet, url: bets_path do |f| %>

  <% if @bet.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@bet.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this bet from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @bet.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :odds %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :odds %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :time_completed %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select(:time_completed, default: 2.days.from_now) %>
  </p>

  <div class='picks' id='bet-<%= @bet.id %>'>
    <h2>Picks</h2>
    <% f.fields_for :picks do |pick_form| %>
      <%= render :partial => '/picks/new', :locals => { :f => pick_form, :pick => pick_form.object } %>
    <% end %>
    <div id='new-picks'>
    </div>
    <p><a href='#' class='pick-add'>add a pick</a></p>
  </div>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', bets_path %>
```

And the corresponding child (partial) view:

```
<%#
locals:
  f - form context
  pick - Pick to be displayed
%>

<div class='pick' id='<%= pick.id %>'>
  <h3>Pick</h3>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :sport %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :sport %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :team %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :team %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :league %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :league %>
  </p>
  <p><a href='#' class='pick-remove'>Remove the pick above</a></p>
</div>
```

The I'm getting this error when I try to open the route which uses the parent view...

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

And the highlighted line is `<div class='pick' id='<%= pick.id %>'>` from the partial view.

Am I missing something obvious here?

---

Edit:

Thanks @BroiSatse, I updated my controller to include `@bet.picks.build`, it now looks like this:

```
  def new
    @bet = Bet.new
    @bet.picks.build
  end
```

But I am getting a `undefined method 'val' for #<Arel::Nodes::BindParam:0x007f9ab7acfbf8` on the line with that addition when I open the view, here's a stacktrace:

```
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:572:in `block (2 levels) in where_values_hash'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:568:in `fetch'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:568:in `block in where_values_hash'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:566:in `map'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:566:in `where_values_hash'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:579:in `scope_for_create'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:503:in `create_scope'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:168:in `initialize_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:248:in `block in build_record'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/core.rb:282:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:131:in `build_association'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:247:in `build_record'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:136:in `build'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:254:in `build'
app/controllers/bets_controller.rb:9:in `new'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

My Bet model:

```
class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :picks, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :picks

  validates :odds, presence: true, numericality: true # { only_integer: true }
  validates :time_completed, presence: true
end
```

My Pick model:

```
class Pick < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bet

  validates :team, presence: true #, length: { minimum: 1 }
  validates :sport, presence: true, inclusion: { :in => ['Basketbal', 'Ice Hockey'] }
  validates :league, presence: true, inclusion: { :in => %w( NBA NHL ) }
end
```

Comment: Are you sure pick_form.object is not nil?

Comment: Ok, could you also show your bet model, it seems there is sth wrong with your association.

Comment: added them now @BroiSatse

Comment: Hmm, weird. All looks all right. Do you have column `bet_id` on `picks` table?

Comment: Oops, I didn't. I added that and now I can see the page again, but still no nested form... @BroiSatse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined `@bet` variable in the controller? If so, change your `form_for` to `form_for @bet`. You will also need `accepts_nested_attributes_for :picks` in your bet model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I tried that, `@bet` is indeed defined, but what happens if I make the change you suggested is that the page doesn't error,  but no partial is displayed.

Comment: @Zen - this is actually a good sign. :) Your @bet has no picks defined so it simply doesn't display any. Add `@bet.picks.build` in your controller and form will show up.

Comment: Getting closer :D, unfortunately that gives me a `undefined method 'val' for #<Arel::Nodes::BindParam:0x007f9ab7acfbf8>` though. Any ideas? (I didn't call a method 'val')

Comment: I just created the project again from scratch and scaffolded my associations, somehow this worked but my other project is broken - they appear the same to my eyes, but oh well, it works now :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, I hope this will help you

```
<% f.fields_for :picks do |pick_form| %>
  <%= render :partial => '/picks/new', :f => pick_form %>
<% end %>
```